tgcrypto install fails building a wheel
I'm trying to install tgcrypto but it fails building a wheel
It says to get Microsoft building tools, but I already installed it. Here is the error
 error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for tgcrypto (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [19 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tests
      copying tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tests
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tests\cbc
      copying tests\cbc\test_cbc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tests\cbc
      copying tests\cbc\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tests\cbc
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tests\ctr
      copying tests\ctr\test_ctr.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tests\ctr
      copying tests\ctr\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tests\ctr
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tests\ige
      copying tests\ige\test_ige.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tests\ige
      copying tests\ige\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\tests\ige
      running build_ext
      building 'tgcrypto' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for tgcrypto
Failed to build tgcrypto
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (tgcrypto)


You are having this error because you are using an unsupported python version. TgCrypto currently supports Python 3.7 - 3.11 but you are using Python 3.12.
Use a supported version of Python to fix this error.
